# Pattern for normalized tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalize

Im fairly new to SQL, so difficult for me to know whats good, bad, better or best design.

I have a SQL 2008 database which I'm using along with Entity Framework 4.3. I'm trying to normalize my database.

In my design I have 2 tables Applications and AcceptedApplications.

AcceptedApplications is simply an extension of the Applications table, for, you guessed it, AcceptedApplications. This simply contains further information that is not pertinent to rejected applications.

There is a foreign key relationship between Application and AcceptedApplications so an Application must exist before an AcceptedApplication can be inserted.

However, I am also contemplating putting a bit  field in the Application table to indicate whether it is accepted or not, something like 'IsAccepted'.

The question is, is this strictly necessary? Being a newbie I'm not necessarily aware of the benfits (if any) over simply checking whether an ID exists in ApplicationAccepted or joining the 2 tables togther. In terms of use I will not be querying for rejected applications on the live website only for analytical/reporting purposes.

Comment: _Why_ are you denormalizing tables?  Usually this runs the risk of getting data-mismatch errors... and is only used to solve performance-related issues.  What additional attributes were in `AcceptedApplications` - and what are you planning on doing with them if you remove that table?

Answer (score 0):

An IsAccepted bit field seems more reasonable.

However, if for some reason there might be another Applications table, for instance for applications in the process of being accepted or that have been refused, with different fields, your current solution seems better.

I believe this to be very unlikely but depending on your actual needs this may sound useful.

Please note that both solutions are in 3rd normal form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that you don't need the two table simply because the `Application` table will suffice your need based in your information. And the field that you want to add to `AcceptedApplication` table, namely, the `IsAccepted` field could simply be added in your `Application` table.

You could probably have this structure for your application table:

Table: **Application**

```
 ApplicationID, Applicant_Lastname, Applicant_Firstname, ApplyDate, IsAccepted, AcceptedDate
```

The key in `Normalization` is interestingly the `primary key`. As E.F. Codd says and I'll be quoting from memory "*Every non-key (meaning not the primary key) must provide a fact on the key (meaning the primary key) and nothing but the key*".

For example the `IsAccepted` field actually is a non-key that is functionally dependent on the primary key `ApplicationID` so no need to create a new table for that matter.

Personally, I use a mnemonic device for the first three normal form, namely, the word **RePeaT** (ignoring the vowels). First is no Repeating groups or multivalued fields, second no Partial dependence on primary key and finally no Transitory dependence.

**First Normal form (1NF)**: No Repeating Groups or Multivalued fields

Example: (**Students** taking **Courses**)

```
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + CourseTakenID  StudentID    CoursesTaken
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + 1               101          CS100, CS102, CS103
  + 2               102          MS100, CS101
```

In this case `CoursesTaken` is a `Multi-valued` fields and is a violation of `1NF`.

To normalized, you could create a separate table named `CourseTaken` (now I am assuming also here that there is already a `Course` table), like:

```
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + CourseTakenID  StudentID    CoursesTaken
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + 1               101          CS100
  + 2               101          CS102
  + 3               101          CS103
  + 4               102          MS100
  + 5               102          CS101
```

Or if a repeating groups, it would look like this:

```
  +--------------------------------------------------------------
  + StudentID  StudentLastName   StudentFirstName   CoursesTaken
  +--------------------------------------------------------------
  + 101        Smith             John             CS100
  + 101        Smith             John             CS102
  + 101        Smith             John             CS103
  + 102        Gilmore           Anna             MS100
  + 102        Gilmore           Anna             CS101
```

To normalize, it would be the same as above however your `Student` table would simply be:

```
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + StudentID  StudentLastName   StudentFirstName  
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + 101        Smith             John             
  + 102        Gilmore           Anna
```

**Second Normal form (2NF)**: No Partial dependence

Now, the `2NF` assumes here that the `primary key` is a `composite primary key` meaning combination of two or more fields.

Example: (**Order Details** of a customer)

Now, below we have an Order Details table that has a composite primary key of `OrderID` and `ProductID`

```
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + OrderID  ProductID   ProductName      Quantity
  +-----------------------------------------------
  + 1        WM101       Washing Machine   1           
  + 2        EI201       Electric Iron     1
```

In this case above `ProductName` is partially dependent on `ProductID` but not on `OrderID` and `ProductID` which are the `composite primary key`.

So, you could normalized this one by removing `ProductName` and put it instead on the `Product` table for example.

`Order Details` table:

```
  +----------------------------------
  + OrderID  ProductID   Quantity
  +----------------------------------
  + 1        WM101         1           
  + 2        EI201         1
```

`Products` table:

```
  +----------------------------------
  + ProductID ProductName   QuantityOnHand
  +----------------------------------
  + WM101     Washing Machine   20           
  + EI201     Electric Iron     40
```

**Third Normal form (3NF)**: No Transitory Dependence

Example: (**Customer** and their corresponding **Sales Representative**)

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  + CustomerID  CustomerLastName   CustomerFirstName   RepID   RepLastName     RepFirstName
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  + 101         James              Grace               SR101   Bravo           Brave
  + 102         Gordon             Ronald              SR102   Alpha           Alfonso
  + 103         Moore              Jeff                SR101   Bravo           Brave
```

In the case above `RepLastName` and `RepFirstName` is dependent on `RepID` while `RepID` is dependent
on `CustomerID` so it is transitional and not a direct dependence on the primary key.

So, to normalized you create a separate table for `SalesRep` that would look like this:

```
  +-----------------------------------------
  + RepID   RepLastName     RepFirstName
  +-----------------------------------------
  + SR101   Bravo           Brave
  + SR102   Alpha           Alfonso
```

And your `Customers` table would now look like this:

```
  +----------------------------------------------------------
  + CustomerID  CustomerLastName   CustomerFirstName   RepID 
  +----------------------------------------------------------
  + 101         James              Grace               SR101 
  + 102         Gordon             Ronald              SR102
  + 103         Moore              Jeff                SR101
```