# can get search query to work c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve data from database based on checkboxes. when user type in textbox and tick all of the text boxes, it will produce a result of all in the database. But the problem is that it says "cannot convert boolean to string" and my searchbook, `library.DatabaseServices.searchBook(string, bool, bool, bool)`: not all code paths return a value. Does anyone have a clue?

*note: nevermind my connectionString, data source. It ok :)

```
[WebMethod]
public string searchBook(String input, Boolean title, Boolean author, Boolean publisher)
{
    string result ="";
    string connectionString =
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source='\\Library\\Book_data\\Lib_item.mdb';";

    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Lib_item WHERE title='" + title + "','" + author + "','" + publisher + "')";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        title = true;
        author = true;
        publisher = true;

        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryString;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        result += "Item added";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "it" is the compiler here, right? As such, the syntax of the connection string is irrelevant; it is just an arbitrary string literal to the compiler. Can you please provide the exact location in the source code where the errors are indicated?

Comment: you need to check you query

Comment: @Ravi, these are *compiler* errors. The query is just a meaningless string at this point, it is completely irrelevant whether it is syntactically or semantically correct as long as the code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The problem is the query string. He is concatenating Booleans to his string, which doesn't work and is giving compiler errors.

Comment: @Tobberoth: Exactly. That is why checking the query will not help, he or she has to check the syntax in the C# code line where the query string is assembled. I'm pointing this out here because the question text does give me a feeling the OP is not aware of that difference.

Answer (score 1):

Title is boolean, you can't add it to a string like you're doing in your queryString. Why is Title Boolean anyway, it should obviously be a string, so your method is probably incorrectly designed.

On top of this, you should not create a querystring like that, it leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks. Read up on SqlParameters and use a parameterized query, it will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

your method arguments `title`, `author` and `publisher` should be `String`, not `Boolean`. Unless you actually store these values in the database as `true` or `false`, but that seems improbable (and illogical).

Furthermore, you should parameterize your SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

title  author and publisher are boolean, but you are using their values to search the database.

Please post your table design if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong:

```
 string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Lib_item WHERE title='" + title + "','" + author + "','" + publisher + "')";
```

The `author`, `title` and `publisher` are treated as `strings` in your query 
when in fact it is `boolean` thus the conversion error.

Let assume that Author, Title and Publisher in your table are really boolean it could probably look like this:

```
 string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Lib_item WHERE title='" + title + "'";
 querystring += " AND hasAuthor = " + author + " AND hasPublisher = " + publisher;
```

But it doubt it, your `Author`, `Title` and `Publisher` should be string instead of boolean and therefore your query could look like this:

```
 string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Lib_item WHERE title='" + title + "'";
 querystring += " AND Author = '" + author + "' AND Publisher = '" + publisher +"'";
```

And by the way if the last query above is how your table looks like then it is not a `Normalized` table which is bad database design if there is one at all.

See my post in [Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188944/pattern-for-normalized-tables/20240854#20240854).

Answer (score 0):

in addition to `parameterizing`, it should be `AND/OR` between `WHERE` clause criteria

```
fld=value and fld=value and fld=value
```

with boolean might be...

```
fld1=value and fld2 and fld3
```

but if looking for a false boolean would be

```
fld1=value and fld2 and not fld3
```

just examples...